# Laravel: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::where()

Tags: php, search, laravel, undefined, where-clause

I am having a problem in this controller function. The function takes an optional 'search' parameter and uses it to search through en employers available jobs for keywords. When I am calling this function I am getting the following error.

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::where()

[image]

Here is my relevant code. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Routes: (prefix: '/api/v1/')

```
Route::get('employer/{employerId}/jobs', 'EmployersController@getJobs');
```

Controller:

```
public function getJobs ($employerId) {

    $search = Input::get('query');

    $jobs = Job::getAvailableByEmployer($employerId, $search);
    return $jobs;
}
```

Model:

```
public static function getAvailableByEmployer($employerId, $search=NULL)
{
    $jobs = Job::where('jobs.employer_id', '=', $employerId)
                ->where('jobs.status', '=', 'Available')
                ->orderBy('jobs.created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();

    if ($search)
    {
        $jobs->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%')
            ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%');
  }

        return $jobs;
}
```

Comment: A hint: `>get();` PS: also think of a precedence for `OR` and `AND`

Comment: I must be missing something pretty obvious here. I have had a look around for a solution involving your hint but appear to be failing hard. sorry brah.

Comment: why do you think `$jobs` must have a `where` or `orWhere` method?

Comment: Because if a search term is supplied it should be able to match it against the title or description. :)

Comment: yep, it should. But `$jobs` object doesn't have a `where` method. When you perform your `if ($search)` code - the `$jobs` are already filtered according the query given in the first lines.

Comment: Ok, so I am not looking for a method like where, instead I'm looking for a method to filter down a finished request?

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhh............. **WHY** do you call a `->get()` method that performs a database data retrieval if the whole query isn't ready yet?

Comment: I'm not sure man, to be honest I didnt write this one. ^^

Comment: I think I got it working, I am not receiving any results but no errors either, I'm sure i can work it out from here. Thanks dude you have been a huge help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your function like this:

```
public function scopeGetAvailableByEmployer($query, $employerId, $search=NULL)
{
    $query->where('employer_id', '=', $employerId)
            ->where('status', '=', 'Available')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');


    if ($search)
    {
        $jobs->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%')
             ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%'. $search .'%');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Now call it like (`scope` lets you call statically):

```
$jobs = Job::getAvailableByEmployer($employerId, $search)->get();
```

Also remember that, once you call `get()` then you can't make any query because that is not a `Query Builder` anymore but a `Collection` object.